# What does the phrase "flip out" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, phrases

I am wondering if the phrase "flip out" is used in an idiomatic sense in the following sentence (used as a title) from the description of the game Infinity Pinball:

> **Flip out** and go retro
>
> In this game the old-school arcade action goes on forever

Here is a description of the game from Google Play:

> Infinity Pinball delivers a revolutionary twist on the pinball genre -
> so the fun never ends! Served up in a nostalgic retro-style, these
> infinitely long procedurally-generated pinball tables live inside a
> virtual Pocket Game. You can continually play your ball up the table
> levels for endless fun as you win coins, collect unique balls and
> unlock new tables.

Answer (score 2):

"Flip out" generally means for someone to demonstrate some degree of mental instability. Here it is simply playing on "flippers" being the usual name for pinball levers.